# P.33 of Karen Smith 'An Invitation to Algebraic Geometry': projective coordinates

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I do not get how to use the coordinate of the projective line at infinity as page 33 says.

Specifically when $x_{0} =0 \in \langle x_{0},x_{1},x_{2} \rangle$ a point is at $\langle x_{1},x_{2} \rangle$ in the projective line in $\mathbb{P}^{2}$; in the previous page a point where $x_{0} =0 \in \langle x_{0},x_{1} \rangle$ is at $\infty$, shouldn't the point be at $x_{1}$ to correspond with the subsequent page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The locus $\{x_0 = 0\}$ in $\mathbb P^2$ is a copy of $\mathbb P^1$, called the "line at infinity", where the projective coordinates are the other two coordinates $x_1, x_2$ on $\mathbb P^2$.  Note that this should not be confused with the point $(x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb C^2$, which corresponds to $\langle 1, x_1, x_2 \rangle \in \mathbb P^2$; the line at infinity is precisely the part of $\mathbb P^2$ that isn't contained in $\mathbb C^2$.

The situation in $\mathbb P^1$ is much the same.  The locus $\{x_0 = 0\}$ in $\mathbb P^1$ is a copy of $\mathbb P^0$, called the "point at infinity".  (Remember that coordinates on projective space are only defined up to scaling by a nonzero constant, so we have $\langle x \rangle = \langle y \rangle$ for all nonzero $x$ and $y$; that is, $\mathbb P^0$ does indeed consist of a single point.)  One usually doesn't impose coordinates on the point at infinity (it is, after all, only one point), but it is perfectly correct to say that it has coordinates $\langle x_1 \rangle$ in $\mathbb P^0$.  Again, this is different from the point $x_1 \in \mathbb C$; the point at infinity is precisely the part of $\mathbb P^1$ that isn't contained in $\mathbb C$.